# How it's done - Laravel Blade statements

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

How it is done, that we can have for example something like this in a blade view:

```
@if (count($records) === 1) 
(...)
```

After analyzing the bladeCompiler.php file, I can see that this is converted to PHP, there is for example a method like this:

```
protected function compileIf($expression)
{
    return "<?php if{$expression}: ?>";
}
```

It is then indirectly used by "compileString" method, which takes and returns a string.

But what then? I can't find an occurence of the PHP's "eval" function call in the entire project, so how it's done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Blade has compiled the PHP code, Laravel puts the result into a cached file in the `storage/framework/views/` directory. That file is then called directly, so you don't need any `eval()` statements.

Comment: Thanks! Just one more question - do you know why does it do it? Isn't it better, easier and faster to use the eval() function? I know "eval" is evil, but in this case it's the same - the framework probably use an "include" statement which also evaluates the code, right?

Comment: I imagine it takes a lot less resources if you can cache the view instead of having to compile it from Blade every time.